# How to create a view that list all child nodes of current page?

Tags: views, 8

I have a content type "A" that has an entity reference field to content type "B".

I need to create a view that will be embed on "A" node page for listing all "B" nodes referenced to it.

I know I have to use contextual filters for getting the current node id and a relationship, but not sure exactly the recipe.

Comment: Use A nid as a contextual filter and list the ERR field as a link to the entity.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a view of content type B. (View Type Block)
2. Create a relationship in that view to the content that contains the reference field by clicking on add a relationship, and search for the name of your reference field)
3. Create a contextual filter to filter by ID using that reference field. Choose "Provide default value" then "Content ID from URL".
4. Display your block on the appropriate pages.